# 2 way binding not working for Directive with ControllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

2 way binding was not working for my directive with ControllerAs syntax,

see example:

```
restrict: "E",
scope: {
    items: "="
},
controller: "itemsController",
controllerAs: "vm",
templateUrl: "items.html",
replace: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Found out that as of Angular 1.3, we need to add bindToController to ensure that items are bind to the controller instead of scope.

see example with bindToController:

```
restrict: "E",
scope: {
    items: "="
},
controller: "itemsController",
controllerAs: "vm",
bindToController: true,
templateUrl: "items.html",
replace: true
```

Now the 2 way binding for items should be working fine.

For more info, read this blog from dan wahlin (http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers)